# HtmlUnit - download background-images

Tags: java, htmlunit

How to force download background-images from css? 
HtmlUnit is ignoring styles like:

```
  <div class="news-item-image" style="background-image: url('https://xxx/uploads/craft-blog-01_190611_101631.png')">
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no direct support for doing that.

You can have a look at Wetator - ResponseStore implementation for a sample doing that (https://wetator.repositoryhosting.com/trac/wetator_wetator/browser/trunk/wetator/src/org/wetator/backend/htmlunit/ResponseStore.java) - start with looking at the method

```
public String processCSS(final URL aFullContentUrl, final String aCssContent, final int aDeep)
```